# Segmentation fault movsb nasm in 64 bits linux

Tags: linux, nasm

I'm new in asm, and trying to use some opcodes for getting my hands on it.
I'm working on linux, 64 bits, and have allways a segmentation fault when using movsb. I compile with nasm:

```
nasm -f elf64 test.asm
```

Here is the code

```
DEFAULT ABS
segment data
    data:
    texte: db 'Hello, World !!', 10, 13
    len: equ $-texte
    texteBis: db 'Hello, World !.', 10, 13

segment code
    global main

main:
    ;The problem is here
    mov rsi, texteBis
    mov rdi, texte
    mov cx, len
    rep movsb

    mov dx, len
    mov rcx, texte
    mov bx, 1
    mov ax, 4

    int 0x80

    mov bx,0        ; exit code, 0=normal
    mov ax,1        ; exit command to kernel
    int 0x80        ; interrupt 80 hex, call kernel
```

Other question, with string (or other large db instance), should I use

```
mov rsi, texte
```

or

```
mov rsi, [texte]
```

I didn't understand which one gives the value and which one the address.

Comment: `[texte]` is semantically equivalent to accessing a pointer in C, e.g. `*texte`. See [Effective Addresses](https://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/manual/html/nasm-effaddr.html).

Comment: In C, texte is already a pointer (because it should be an array), that's why I'm confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Do you also link?

```
ld -e main test.o -o test
```

Anyways, `texteBis` seems to be static data, in the data segment. That page is read-only and protected for writing/execution.

You should allocate a buffer (either on the stack or on the heap if you are allowed to use a runtime library).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that **you are writing to write-protected memory**, i.e. the `DATA` section. Once your program gets loaded into the memory, the `DATA` section is actually on a read-only page. You have to use stack memory (or dynamically allocated memory) and use that as the destination of your string copy.

Example:

```
sub rsp, len        ; move stack pointer down 'len' bytes
mov rsi, texteBis  
mov rdi, rsp        ; use address of stack pointer as dest.
xor rcx,rcx         ; cx = 0
mov cx, len
rep movsb
```

That should fix your problem. As in C, it is important to allocate enough space or you will overwrite data on the stack.

#### Assigning values to registers

Another thing that I noticed is that you often write to sub-parts of registers, e.g.

```
mov dx, len
```

This is dangerous since other parts are not overwritten by this. Only the lowest 16 bit of the register are written. Say `rdx`, a 64 bit value was set to `0xffffffffffffffff`. Then `rdx` would look like this after your move: `0xffffffffffff0011`. The calling code probably reads `rdx` completely and therefore interprets a length of `0xffffffffffff0011` byte. Not what you want. Solution:

```
xor rdx,rdx
mov  dx, len
```

or

```
mov rdx, len
```

#### Tools that might help you later

Note, `gdb` will help you find where your error is happening and will also give you additional information (such as register values and stack values). Excerpt:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004005bb in main ()
(gdb) disassemble 
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x00000000004005a6:  sub    $0x13,%rsp
   0x00000000004005aa:  mov    -0x1c(%rip),%rsi        # 0x400595
   0x00000000004005b1:  mov    %rsp,%rdi
   0x00000000004005b4:  xor    %cx,%cx
   0x00000000004005b7:  mov    $0x11,%cx
=> 0x00000000004005bb:  rep movsb %ds:(%rsi),%es:(%rdi)
   0x00000000004005bd:  mov    $0x11,%dx
   0x00000000004005c1:  movabs $0x400584,%rcx
   0x00000000004005cb:  mov    $0x1,%bx
   0x00000000004005cf:  mov    $0x4,%ax
   0x00000000004005d3:  int    $0x80
   0x00000000004005d5:  mov    $0x0,%bx
   0x00000000004005d9:  mov    $0x1,%ax
   0x00000000004005dd:  int    $0x80
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) info registers rsi
rsi            0x57202c6f6c6c6548   6278066737626506568
```

Since `nasm` does not support a useful debugging format but it is often the case that you want to break on certain occasions, you can use the `int3` instruction to raise a `SIGTRAP` at a certain point in the code:

```
 mov eax, 10
 int3         ; debugger will catch signal here
```

Hope that helps getting you started in assembly.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me.
Just a question more : I don't find in the nasm documentation how to define a stack segment (only "segment stack stack" exist, but for obj format). How can I allocate memory for it ?

Comment: never mind, I used the section .bss for allocating enough space for using movsb. Thank you (I thought that data section was writable).

Comment: .data section is indeed writable

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use dynamic memory. Your data segment or section is read-only because is not an standard section and you are not defining it's attributes and by default nasm assign them as read only data sections.

Using `objdump -h` with you code outputs the following:

```
  0 data          00000022  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000200  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  1 code          0000003c  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000230  2**0
              CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, DATA
```

If you change the name of your segements to `.data` and `.text` the program runs perfectly and `objdump` outputs:

```
0 .data         00000022  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000200  2**2
              CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
1 .text         0000003c  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000230  2**4
              CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
```

Which are the correct attributes for what you intend with your sections.

To get more info on what attributes means I recommend this page:
https://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/manual/html/objfmt-elf-section.html